# On the measurement of charge in motion

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

In the book by Purcell, "Electricity and Magnetism", he expresses the need to detect moving charges using a force. But at that point it is impossible to infer as coulombs law fails. Instead he follows a method through which he manages to find the average of all the forces in all the direction, in a sphere. Surprisingly he uses Gauss's law in doing so.
The following are my question:-

1. In finding the force on a test charge, the author does the following.

> To allow for this possibility, let’s agree to define $Q$ by averaging over all directions. Imagine a large number of infinitesimal test charges distributed evenly over a sphere (. At the instant the moving charge passes the center of the sphere, the radial component of force on each test charge is measured, and the average of these force magnitudes is used to compute $Q$. Now this is just the operation that would be needed

How is the author certain that the force is just coulombs law, and how can we say anything about the direction, its angular dependence of the force?

2. How is gauss's law even used for this situation as this isn't even an electrostatic case?

Comment: Gauss' Law is one of Maxwells equations, it is valid in electrodynamic situations as all the rest of them are.

Comment: Even when charges are in motion? Could you be a little explicit

Comment: It's simply because Maxwells equations are the basis for electrodynamics, so yes they are all valid in nonstatic cases.

Comment: Could you provide an elementary proof, or to which property of electromagnetism in general is it related?

Comment: The elementary proofs are in any textbook on electrodynamics, eg Jacksons Classical Electrodynamics.

Comment: Please, (if possible) provide a link or pdf

Comment: @Triatticus Could you also provide the logic between the determination of charge whilst in motion.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on mobile, hopefully someone can help with the primary part of your question.

Comment: _he expresses the need to detect moving charges using a force. But at that point it is impossible to infer_ In general this is FALSE. That's exactly how [bubble chambers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) work. Measuring charged particle trajectory radius, one can determine Lorentz force acting on the particle and consequently - it's charge.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that Gauss's law holds. This is simply a mathematical tool that consists of counting field lines. **At a given instant**, the charges outside the surface do not affect the total flux; only the charges inside produce field lines that do not cancel and contribute to the total flux. Therefore, the value does not depend on the surface we use.

Another question is whether the value depends on whether the charges inside move in one way or another. It is shown experimentally that the charge of a system does not depend on its state of motion. Therefore, the value of the integral depends only on the number and variety of charges inside the surface, not on their state of motion.

Regarding the first question: the author is not saying that the force is Coulomb's law. In fact, to measure the charge you don't need to know it. You simply measure the force, whatever it is, on each test charge. The field at that point will be the force per unit charge. Calculate the aforementioned integral and you will have the total charge.

> The field
> $E$ is measured, at any point $(x, y, z)$ and at time $t$ in $F$, by the force
> on a test charge at rest in $F$, at that time and place. The surface integral is to be determined for a particular time $t$.